# Increment and decrement counter on checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working with Next.js to handle a question form that has different kinds of questions with single choice answers and multiple choice. I have a progress bar in which its percentages change according to selected answers. when I select a question's answer I increment a `counter` and when I unselect an answer decrement the `counter`.

1 - When I select a checkbox of a question at first increment the `counter`, but it must not increment when I select the second checkbox in the same question.

2 - When I unselect multiple-choice questions answer it must not decrement if any one of them is selected it must not decrement until the last one is unselected.

Now when selecting the first time it increments the `counter` but after that, if I select or unselect, it decrements.

Please help me to handle this.

**Question sample:**

[image]

**This is my code:**

```
 <MuilteSelectQuestion
      key={item.attributes.Number}
      id={item.attributes.Number}
      data={item}
      name={`${item.attributes.Number}`}
      handleMultiChecked={handleMultiChecked}
  />
```

**The component:**

```
<div className="relative flex items-start">
    {Object.keys(attributes?.options).map(item => (
      <>
          <div className="flex items-center h-5">
               <input
                   {...feild}
                   {...props}
                   id={item}
                   type="checkbox"
                   name={`${name}[]`}
                   value={`${item}`}
                   onClick={e =>
                    handleMultiChecked(
                      `question${id}`,
                      e.target.checked
                    )
                   }
                   className="focus:ring-indigo-500 h-4 w-4 text-indigo-600 border-gray-300 rounded"
               />
            </div>
            <div className="ml-2 mr-3 text-sm">
                 <label
                    htmlFor={item}
                    className="font-medium text-gray-700"
                 >
                   {item}
                 </label>
            </div>
        </>
     ))}
 </div>
```

**The function:**

```
 function handleMultiChecked(val, checked) {
    setCompareTitle(val);
    if (val !== compareTitle && checked) {
        setCounter(++counter);
    } else {
       setCounter(--counter);
    }
}


useEffect(() => {
    setPercent((parseInt(counter) / parseInt(dataCount)) * 100);
}, [counter]);
```

**The data that come from backend:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you have another state to track all questions' counters

```
const [questionCounters, setQuestionCounters] = useState({})
```

Apply it to `handleMultiChecked`

```
function handleMultiChecked(val, checked) {
    setCompareTitle(val);

    const currentQuestionCounter = questionCounters[val] || 0 // if this question is not in the state, the default counter will be 0

    const updatedQuestionCounter = checked ? currentQuestionCounter + 1 : currentQuestionCounter - 1 //update the current question's counter based on checked

    //no ticks on the current question, we decrease the main counter
    if (currentQuestionCounter === 1 && updatedQuestionCounter === 0) {
        setCounter(--counter);
    }

    //first tick, we increase the main counter
    if(currentQuestionCounter === 0 && updatedQuestionCounter === 1) {
        setCounter(++counter);
    }

    //apply the latest counters' changes for question list
    setQuestionCounters({
       ...questionCounters,
       [val]: updatedQuestionCounter
    })
}


useEffect(() => {
    setPercent((parseInt(counter) / parseInt(dataCount)) * 100);
}, [counter]);
```

Comment: I used your code, when I select a checkbox in a question it works correctly, but if I select two multi checkboxes in a question and when I unselect them, the first one increments and the second one decrements, but if I selected 3 checkboxes, the first one doesn't increment or decrement, but the second increment one and the third one decrement one.

Comment: Could you give me your `item` data? That would help me to understand your case better @ZiaYamin

Comment: I have updated my question. it can be more questions. there is not just one question.

Comment: here when I used your code when I select multiple options, the value of ``questionCounters`` update in every selection, like 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: `item.attributes.Number` is your question id, right? @ZiaYamin

Comment: yes, it is my question id.

Comment: After this line `{Object.keys(attributes?.options).map(item => (`, could you try to add `<div className="flex items-center h-5" key="item">` and remove `<></>` too? @ZiaYamin

Comment: Here is the doc for it https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys @ZiaYamin

Comment: I added, so what shoud do next?

Comment: Could you check my updated code in the answer? I modified it a bit to make sure `counter` state updated correctly with `questionCounters` state @ZiaYamin

Comment: Thank you, bro, now it works correctly, thanks a million for putting your time to solve my problem.